# How to collect logs of every job of a Kubernetes CronJob for a period of time?

Tags: logging, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-cronjob

Assume I have a Kubernetes `CronJob`

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: cron-job-logging
spec:
  schedule: "@hourly"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: cron-job-logging
            image: python:3
            args:
            - /usr/bin/python3
            - -c
            - import random; print('a') if random.random() < 0.5 else print('b')
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

which runs on a GKE cluster 1.14.x with Cloud Operation for GKE activated for "System and workload logging and monitoring".

How can I collect the output for period t (let's say a month) so that I can see whether the pod printed `a` or `b`.

If seen some issues about this request, like https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/27768. The logs seem to be available for some users, but not for others which might be caused by the fact that `CronJobs` are a beta feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've deployed your cronjob, and just for example purposes I set schedule to run each 1 minute, Below there are a few ways on how to access it:

- **GKE console**  – In the  [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/workload)  section of Google Cloud Console, select the Kubernetes resources listed in  **Workloads**, and then the  **Container**  or  **Audit Logs**  links, this method is kind of a shortcut for the next option: *cloud logging console*
- **Cloud Logging console**  – You can see your logs directly from the  [Cloud Logging console](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs)  by using the logging filters to select the Kubernetes resources, such as cluster, node, namespace, pod, or container logs. Here are sample  [Kubernetes-related queries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/query-library-preview#kubernetes-filters)  to help get you started.

  - This is the query I used (redacted project details):

    ```
    resource.type="k8s_container"
    resource.labels.project_id="PROJECT_NAME"
    resource.labels.location="ZONE"
    resource.labels.cluster_name="CLUSTER_NAME"
    resource.labels.namespace_name="NAMESPACE"
    labels.k8s-pod/job-name:"cron-job-logging-"
    ```
  - Here are the result:
    [image]
- **Cloud Monitoring console**  – If you have enabled a Cloud Monitoring Workspace, in the  [Kubernetes Engine](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/dashboards/resourceList/kubernetes)  section of the Cloud Monitoring console, select your  [cluster, nodes, pod, or containers](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/observing#alerting-details)  to view your logs.
- **`gcloud`  command-line tool**  – Using the  [`gcloud logging read`](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/tools/gcloud-logging)  command, select the appropriate cluster, node, pod, and container logs.
- Here an example:

```sh
$ gcloud logging read "resource.labels.project_id=PROJECT AND resource.labels.cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME AND labels.k8s-pod/job-name:cron-job-logging-"
---
insertId: 6vorvd43akuvy8fi3
labels:
  k8s-pod/controller-uid: c525bbae-c6c9-11ea-931b-42010a80001f
  k8s-pod/job-name: cron-job-logging-1594838040
logName: projects/PROJECT/logs/stdout
receiveTimestamp: '2020-07-15T18:35:14.937645549Z'
resource:
  labels:
    cluster_name: CLUSTER_NAME
    container_name: cron-job-logging
    location: ZONE
    namespace_name: default
    pod_name: cron-job-logging-1594838040-pngsk
    project_id: PROJECT
  type: k8s_container
severity: INFO
textPayload: |
  a
timestamp: '2020-07-15T18:34:09.907735144Z'
```

More info here: [GKE - Using Logs](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/using-logs)

If you have any question, let me know in the comments.